# Testing simple function with Gmock - test fails(should pass?)

Tags: googletest, googlemock

I just started using Gtest/Gmocks and I'm struggling with an example. I have a simple class which has a member a function that returns a value(say 3). I'm trying to mock this test and check if the returned result is 3. For simplicity I wrote everything in a single file:

```
// Testing.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "gmock\gmock.h"
#include "gtest\gtest.h"
using ::testing::AtLeast;
using namespace std;

class MyClass{
public:
    virtual int retValue() { return 3; } 
    virtual ~MyClass(){}
};


class FakeMyClass : public MyClass
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0( retValue, int() );
};

TEST(TestForMyClass, TestRetVal)
{
    FakeMyClass obj3;
    EXPECT_EQ(obj3.retValue(), 3);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

However my test fails and it says that expected result is 3 and my actual result is 0.
I've watched a couple of examples and I think I did everything as shown in there still the result is not what I'm expecting. Please help me see where I'm wrong and how can I make that test to pass. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is:
You have an object of your mock `FakeMyClass`. This object will never return the value of the base class, if you override this method!!

If you want to test a simple method of a class, you do not need a mock. Just test your class:

```
class MyClass{
public:
  virtual int retValue() { return 3; } 
  virtual ~MyClass(){}
};

TEST(TestForMyClass, TestRetVal)
{
  MyClass obj3;
  EXPECT_EQ(obj3.retValue(), 3);
}
```

Little bit more to mocking:
A principle of testing is to test in isolation. So, when your class is in a relation to another object, you have to mock this object. I suggest to take a look on an example
 (e.g. [klick](http://docs.biicode.com/c++/examples/gmock.html)).
In this example the `Painter` is the system under test. The `Painter`communicates with the `Turtle`, which is mocked.

Comment: hello Soeren thank you for your answer. I know I do not need to do that mock in my case it was just for learning purposes. I know I can simply test the class'es method but I want to learn understanding the principles of mocking.

Comment: hello Soeren thank you for your answer. I know I do not need to do that mock in my case it was just for learning purposes. I know I can simply test the class'es method but I want to learn understanding the principles of mocking.Can you please explain how could I use a workaround so that I can test that the returnValue function indeed returns 3 using mocks?

Comment: No, this is not the purpose of mocking. Furthermore your question was: why is my actual result not 3. And I gave the answer to that question. I suggest you to take a deeper look into mocking and testing.